# Plotting the security function without the horizontal lines?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

If I run this script

```
Custom_time_frame_close = security(syminfo.tickerid, '12M', close)
plot(Custom_time_frame_close)
```

the plot will have many horizontal lines like such

[image]

How can remove the horizontal lines so that it looks identical to if I was using the 1 year resolution (without changing to the 1 year resolution)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the yearly close dataseries it contains every new value at the end of the year(close) and has no information about the intra-year changes.

The easiest workaround is to smooth the dataseries with Simple Moving Average:

```
//@version=4
study("")
Custom_time_frame_close = security(syminfo.tickerid, '12M', close)
plot(Custom_time_frame_close)

Smoothed_custom_time_frame_close = sma(Custom_time_frame_close, 50)
plot(Smoothed_custom_time_frame_close, color = color.red)
```

Otherwise instead of the security call you'll have to calculate the intra-year values from the current timeframe's data.

Comment: It seems that a chart identical in shape can be achieved by using the correct length for the SMA, which is security function resolution/chart resolution.